# Codename One: Android release build

Tags: build, codenameone

I'm currently having problems building a release-version for Android.
The keystore file/password/alias are correct and I've set "Generate Builds" to release, but I'm still getting the following notification:

> Warning: Building for Android without a valid certificate will produce a temporary certificate that cannot be used for redistribution of applications. Its very easy and free to create an Android certificate, see: http://www.codenameone.com/signing.html

I have successfully used this certificate before, about two years ago...

I'm using NetBeans 8.1 with the CN1-plugin 3.3.2.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means Codename One didn't find the file or the password/alias are incorrect.

You can use the keytool to verify this:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore full_path_to_keystore -alias myalias
```

Make sure the alias/path are identical to what you see in NetBeans.

Comment: It seems that at some point during these two years, I removed one space-character from a folder-name, so the path was indeed incorrect. -.-